# How to say "I can't help but..."

Tags: word-choice

From a lesson in a Chinese text book was the following sentence:

> 他不由得哭 (Tā bùyóude kū)

*He could not help but cry*

I've never heard 不由得 used in a sentence, and I want to know if it is common and if not, what is typically used.

The sentence I was hoping to say is:

> "I can't help but blame you"

Google translate offers the following:

> 我不禁责怪你

In particular I want spoken Chinese rather than written if there is a difference.

Answer (score 6):

There are actually two meanings of *"can't help but"* here, with a rather subtle distinction. In your first example, the guy cannot control the fact that he wants to cry - he simply let go of his emotions. In your second example, you *can* control your behavior, and in fact you're very *determined* to do it.

In the first example, an equivalent phrase would be:

> 不由自主地 (did something without control)

In the second example, an equivalent phrase would be

> 没有办法不[责怪你]  (have no choice but to [blame you]).

You're right that the phrase 不由得 is rarely used. In fact, when it is used, it usually has a different meaning: telling another person "You have no choice", e.g.

> 这件事情不由得你 = You have no say in this matter

Comment: Thanks for this, you picked it out well. Sometimes I have trouble seeing things when they are the said the same way in English.

Comment: For `这件事情不由得你`, I think `这件事情由不得你` is more common.

Answer (score 5):

First, both of your examples are a little awkward. The following changes make them more natural Chinese sentences:

> 他不由得哭了。
>
> 我不禁要责怪你。

Second, yes, both 不由得 and 不禁 are more common in written instead of spoken Chinese. A colloquial expression will be 忍不住:

> 他忍不住哭了。
>
> 我忍不住要责怪你。

`... can't help but ...` implies `I don't want to do so but I can't control my feelings.` So does 忍不住.

For your first example, you can also use 不由自主地. It has the same meaning, but is more of written style.

> 他不由自主地哭了。

As for other suggestions such as 不得不 and 没法不, the meaning is a little different. It means `I don't want to but the objective circumstances compels me to do so.` It is more a description of the physical world than an expression of the psychological mood.

> 他不得不哭。(In this case, there is no 了 at the end of the sentence. He had to cry but we do not know if he actually cried. The same below.)
>
> 他没法不哭。
>
> 我不得不责怪你。
>
> 我没法不责怪你。

Answer (score 2):

`I can't help but`
 在你的两个例子中, `忍不住`是最好的选择. 表达了人物想控制, 但是控制不住自己的情绪.

In your example, `忍不住` is the best fit choice. It express the person that want to control himself but failed.

Answer (score 0):

The best direct translation to the phrase `... can't help but...` that I can think of is `...不得不...`

> He can't help but cry - 他不得不哭
>
> I can't help but to blame you - 我不得不责怪你
>
> I can't help but to think of you - 我不得不想你

The phrase `...不得不...` basically means one might not want to do something, but is compelled by whatever reason to it anyway.  Which is very similar to the meaning of the English phrase `... can't help but...`.

Comment: If you say 他不得不哭in Chinese, that means someone forces him to cry